# Using NSS for calling pkcs#11 functions

Tags: c++, aes, pkcs#11, nss

I want to use NSS (Network Security Services) for using AES functions through pkcs#11 interface, but I can not find any example. I use C++ for calling pkcs#11 functions.

How should I do it?

Comment: What is wrong with your current situation? Directly calling PKCS#11 should be preferred. If you want to use NSS, is there any reason not to use the build in AES functionality of the soft-token?

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for your comment, which soft-token you mean? (Every soft-token that I found doesn't have AES implementation.) I Don't know how to install NSS and where is its shared object after installation. I appreciate if you can help me to use NSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search on the internet, I found another soft token, so I use the new soft token instead of NSS. The new soft token is OpenCryptoki. You can see more about this token in the fallowing link:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/s-pkcs/

Comment: The link is dead.